# creating a function, that takes a function as a paramter and calls it on each linkedlist item

Tags: scala, linked-list

we are given a linked list class, and we need to create a function in this class which takes a function as a parameter, and calls that function on each node of the list. we can do it recursively or through loops and I'm not sure why I can't get this to work.

currently im using a while loop where if the node doesent equal null call the function on that node, and then goto the next node.

```
   class LinkedListNode[A](var value: A, var next: LinkedListNode[A]) {
   def calleachnode(inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit = {
    var node = this
    while(node != null){
      inputfunction(node.value)
      node = node.next
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: `this` will never be **null**. Did you mean `node` instead?

Comment: yes sorry, a typo when retyping into stack.

Answer (score 2):

This type of task is best done with (tail) recursion (also, never use `var`, unless you are *completely* certain why you need it ... and also, `null` is also something to avoid, use `Option` instead):

```
case class Node[A](value: A, next: Option[Node[A]]) {
   @tailrec
   final def calleachnode(f: A => Unit): Unit = {
     f(value)
     next match {
       case Some(next) => next.calleachnode(f)
       case None => ()

     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 possibilities that uses `Algebraic Data Types (ADT)`.

First an `object-oriented` way:

```
sealed trait LinkedListNode[A] {
  def calleachnode(inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit 
}

case class BranchNode[A](value:A, next: LinkedListNode[A]) extends LinkedListNode[A] {
  def calleachnode(inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit = {
    inputfunction(value)
    next.calleachnode(inputfunction)
  }
}

case class LeafNode[A](value:A) extends LinkedListNode[A] {
  def calleachnode(inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit = {
    inputfunction(value)
  }
}
```

Or if you prefer you can use pattern matching:

```
sealed trait LinkedListNode[A] {

  def calleachnode(inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit = this match {
    case BranchNode(value, next) => 
        inputfunction(value)
        next.calleachnode(inputfunction)
    case LeafNode(value) =>
        inputfunction(value)
  }
}

case class BranchNode[A](value:A, next: LinkedListNode[A]) extends LinkedListNode[A]

case class LeafNode[A](value:A) extends LinkedListNode[A]
```

You can test these solutions with:

```
 val lln = BranchNode(12, LeafNode(2))
 lln.calleachnode((i) => println(i * 2))
```

Now a more `functional` way to use `ADT`:

```
sealed trait LinkedListNode[A] 

case class BranchNode[A](value:A, next: LinkedListNode[A]) extends LinkedListNode[A]

case class LeafNode[A](value:A) extends LinkedListNode[A]


def calleachnode[A](listNode: LinkedListNode[A], inputfunction : A => Unit): Unit = listNode match {
  case BranchNode(value, next) => 
    inputfunction(value)
    calleachnode(next, inputfunction)
  case LeafNode(value) =>
    inputfunction(value)
}
```

The test looks a bit different:

```
val lln = BranchNode(12, LeafNode(2))
calleachnode[Int](lln, (i) => println(i * 2))
```